# Accessing COM device names in C++/Win7

Tags: c++, windows-7, serial-port

I'm trying to write a program that sends COM port information to devices that may get unplugged and end up with a different COM port number. Using SetupDi, I know it's possible to list all the COM ports on a computer by number, but given that the number might change I'm trying to find a better way to access the COM ports.

The COM devices I'm using are FTDI serial-to-com adapters that let me program the device model. I'd love to be able to choose a COM port based on the device model. I've tried (almost) all of the properties that I can get to using SetupDi, but no dice. It looks like there's a difference between the device list SetupDi lets me access, and the devices that show up under Devices and Printers (where the model name does show up). Is there any way to get devices in the Devices and Printers window programmatically and map them to COM port using Windows APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below is a great (if not the only) comprehensive overview on how to enumerate COM ports on Windows and extract extra information in various ways:

http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html

What we use in our own software (Docklight) is according to what the "UsingSetupAPI1" way from the enumser.cpp file shows (SetupAPI - GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT). The UsingSetupAPI1 example demonstrates how to extract the device name as shown in the Windows Device Manager, along with the COM number. This is called "friendlyNames" in the enumser.cpp code.

Another way to identify and communicating to your device could be not asking Windows in the first place, but the FTDI D2XX API:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples.htm

We use the D2XX API for communication when we know it is always a FTDI device. Identification is simpler and we have much better performance / less latency than using Windows Communications API via "virtual COM port".

If we need to correlate between COM port numbers and a FTDI device ID, we use the FTDI D2XX API's ListDevices and GetComPortNumber functions.

Comment: The FTDI API function to get the COM port number only works if you open the port with FT_OpenEX. This will fail if the port is already open in another program. So the FTDI library is not a generic solution.

Comment: @BrianB ,  that is correct.